# powershell case insensitive condition

Tags: powershell, case

```
$so= Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the OS'
$vm= Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the name'

##Querty
 Get-VM | Where-Object { $_.Name.Contains($vm.ToLower()) -or $_.Name.Contains($vm.ToUpper()) -and $_.Guest.OSFullName.Contains($so) } | Select Name |ft
```

Input the SO: **red**
Input the VMname: **pprd**

Gets "Name" if the variable $so contains "red" and the name contains the value $vm. But, into the object, the SO is in Sentence Case (Red), so the condition is not working.

How can I make the query without distinguishing between upper and lower case letters?

Into the object $_.Guest.OSFullName, exists more strings: SUSE, Red, Ubuntu, Microsoft, etc.

Comment: `.Contains(..)` is by default case sensitive. if you want a partial match assuming `$_.Guest.OSFullName` is a string, you could use `-match` assuming you're not using regex characters in `$so`. If you want an exact match, use `-eq`

Comment: Into the object, exists more strings: SUSE, Red, Ubuntu, etc., that's why I can't do conditional sentence between a exactly word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PowerShell [string matching operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#matching-operators), which are case-insensitive by default, as opposed to .NET string methods.

```sh
Get-VM | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*$vm*" -and $_.Guest.OSFullName -like "*$so*" } | 
    Format-Table -Property Name
```

Table format doesn't make much sense for a single property. To output just the names:

```sh
Get-VM | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*$vm*" -and $_.Guest.OSFullName -like "*$so*" } | 
    ForEach-Object Name
```